# Indent "columns" consistently with varying data in a Jinja2 loop

Tags: python, jinja2

I am trying to build a dns file using a jinja template. I am looping through hostnames and IP's to render to the template. I would like this file to be neat and have consistent indentation. The issue I am having is hostname lengths can vary, so using a filter like indent does not work as expected.

The data looks like so:
host1 192.168.1.2 
host001 192.168.1.3

My template is as follows:

```
{% for host in hosts %}
    {{- host.hostname }} {{ host.ipv4 | indent(10, true) }}
{% endfor %}
```

The result:

```
host1          192.168.1.2
host001          192.168.1.3
```

I would like the IP address "column" to line up with each other so it looks like so:

```
host1          192.168.1.2
host001        192.168.1.3
```

Is this possible to do with Jinja? I am using jinja version 2.7.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
{% for host in hosts %}
    {{- host.hostname }} {{ host.ipv4 | indent(15 - host.hostname|length, true) }}
{% endfor %}
```

Assuming that your hostname is less than 15 characters.

Comment: Worked perfect. Not sure how I didn't think of that. Thank you!